# how represent the properties in spring application.properties as a Map<String,List<String>>

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to read some properties from spring boot `application.properties`.

The properties are in this format

```
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.tas=ims_rmt_server,contact
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.ims=product,kafka
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.uag=realm,Cassandra
```

I need to read these properties as a Map.
The map should contain the keys as `tas,ims,uag`, its value should be list of the corresponding values.

```
[
  tas -> [ims_rmt_server,contact]
  ims-> [product,kafka]
  uag-> [realm,Cassandra]
]
```

I tried the below configuration but I get an exception

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "vnfc.audit.ignore.list")
public class MyAppProperties {
    private Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, List<String>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, List<String>> tas) {
    this.map = tas;
    }
}
```

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'vnfc.audit.ignore.list.tas' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<java.lang.String>>:

Property: vnfc.audit.ignore.list.tas
Value: "ims_rmt_server,contact"
Origin: class path resource [application.properties] - 1:28
Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<java.lang.String>>]

Action:

Update your application's configuration


Process finished with exit code 1
```

please help.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please add some code to show what you attempted to do. In theory just defining a property of `Map<String, List<String>>` should do the trick.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code I tried. Thanks.

Comment: Your `map` property should be named `list` and the prefix must be `vnfc.audit.ignore` instead of `vnfc.audit.ignore.list`. That way it will bind to the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also work in the standard key-value format. The logic in the question is correct. Here's my example, feel free to use whatever you prefer:

**Config.java**

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "vnfc.audit.ignore.list")
    @Bean(name = "ignoreList")
    public Map<String, List<String>> getIgnoreList() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```java
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@SpringBootApplication
@Log4j2
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ignoreList")
    private Map<String, List<String>> ignoreList;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        log.info(ignoreList);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use constructor injection (preferred).

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@SpringBootApplication
@Log4j2
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    private final Map<String, List<String>> ignoreList;

    // Constructor injection
    protected DemoApplication(Map<String, List<String>> ignoreList) {
        this.ignoreList = ignoreList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        log.info(ignoreList);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.tas=ims_rmt_server,contact
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.ims=product,kafka
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.uag=realm,Cassandra
```

**Result**

```
{uag=[realm, Cassandra], ims=[product, kafka], tas=[ims_rmt_server, contact]}
```

Comment: I added an alternative approach using constructor injection. Spring will attempt to wire the bean for you, as long as the type and name are appropriate.

Comment: Also, if you're using Lombok, you can use the `@AllArgsConstructor` to have a constructor generated for you.

Comment: There is a syntax error in `public Map<String, List<String>> getIgnoreList)` in the `Config.java` code listing. A `(` is missing after `getIgnoreList`.

Comment: I fixed the typo

Answer (score 1):

The keys of your map need to be part of the left side and wrapped in `[]`. Also in your example the property `map` is missing. The following should work:

```
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.map[tas]=ims_rmt_server,contact
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.map[ims]=product,kafka
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.map[uag]=realm,Cassandra
```

Your example with the missing `map` added also works:

```
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.map.tas=ims_rmt_server,contact
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.map.ims=product,kafka
vnfc.audit.ignore.list.map.uag=realm,Cassandra
```

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Sorry I edited my question. Your comment maybe outdated :). I also missed the `map` property in my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having all of them in a single property, this different approach will work with with .properties files

```
vnfc.audit.ignore.list={tas: {'ims_rmt_server','contact'}, ims: {'product','kafka'}, uag: {'realm','Cassandra'}}
```

Then in java you can read it like this:

```java
@Value("#{${vnfc.audit.ignore.list}}")
public Map<String, List<String>> auditIgnoreList;
```